# Expand rows given a reference table in Tidyverse

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a table of products / quantities (`name` and `quantity`) looking as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_name <- tibble::tribble(
               ~name, ~quantity,
               "aaa",         1,
             "set_1",         2,
               "bbb",         1,
               "ccc",         2,
             "set_2",         1
             )

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  name  quantity
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 aaa          1
2 set_1        2
3 bbb          1
4 ccc          2
5 set_2        1
```

Sometimes, a product is identified as a `set` (think of a bunlde) containing different single products.

I created a reference tables for the `set` composition:

```
df_reference <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~set_name, ~name,
                    "set_1", "aaa",
                    "set_1", "fff",
                    "set_2", "eee",
                    "set_2", "ccc"
                  )

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  set_name name 
  <chr>    <chr>
1 set_1    aaa  
2 set_1    fff  
3 set_2    eee  
4 set_2    ccc
```

I would like to *expand* the initial df containing products and bunldes having only the products, as follows:

```
df_final <- tibble::tribble(
              ~name, ~value,
              "aaa",      1,
              "aaa",      2,
              "fff",      2,
              "bbb",      1,
              "ccc",      2,
              "eee",      1,
              "ccc",      1
              )

# A tibble: 7 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 aaa       1
2 aaa       2
3 fff       2
4 bbb       1
5 ccc       2
6 eee       1
7 ccc       1
```

Is there an easy way to do it in dplyr?

I suspect that this could be also achieved with a `join` verb but I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df_name %>%
  left_join(df_reference, by = c("name" = "set_name")) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(!is.na(name.y), name.y, name)) %>%
  select(-name.y)

# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   name  quantity
#  <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 aaa          1
# 2 aaa          2
# 3 fff          2
# 4 bbb          1
# 5 ccc          2
# 6 eee          1
# 7 ccc          1
```

Comment: A variant with `coalesce` `df_name %>% 
  left_join(df_reference, by = c("name" = "set_name")) %>% 
  mutate(name = coalesce(name.y, name), .keep = "unused", .before = 2)`